# Do I need a configuration file on each Ceph node?

Tags: ceph

I am getting different things from different sources.  At first I thought that I could just have one configuration file (on the monitor), with sections for each node (include osd nodes).  But when on the new OSD, `ceph osd create` fails, saying there is no configuration file.

So, how does the configuration structure of ceph work?  Further, is the FSID (a UUID) in each configuration file the same?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every machine planned to deploy `osd/mon/mds` should have a `/etc/ceph/ceph.conf` file.

When creating `osd` instance, it needs to communicate with `mon` from configure file. The `fsid` should be same, as `osd/mds/mon` will compare the `fsid` when handling internal messages; if they are not the same, the message will be dropped.